# Spark Dataset - How to create a new column by modifying an existing column value

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a Dataset like below

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = ...
dataset.show()

| NAME | DOB      |
+------+----------+
| John | 19801012 |
| Mark | 19760502 |
| Mick | 19911208 |
```

I want to convert it to below (formatted DOB)

```
| NAME | DOB        |
+------+------------+
| John | 1980-10-12 |
| Mark | 1976-05-02 |
| Mick | 1991-12-08 |
```

How can I do this? Basically, I am trying to figure out how to manipulate existing column string values in a generic way.

I tried using `dataset.withColumn` but couldn't quite figure out how to achieve this.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Those who downvoted, can u please explain why so that I avoid in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the data into a dataframe(deltaData) and just use the following line

```
deltaData.withColumn("DOB", date_format(to_date($"DOB", "yyyyMMdd"), "yyyy-MM-dd")).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

With "substring" and "concat" functions:

```
df.withColumn("DOB_FORMATED",
  concat(substring($"DOB", 0, 4), lit("-"), substring($"DOB", 5, 2), lit("-"), substring($"DOB", 7, 2)))
```

Comment: In java: dataset.withColumn("DOB", concat(substring(col("DOB"), 0, 4), lit("-"), 
     substring(col("DOB"), 5, 2), lit("-"), substring(col("DOB"), 7, 2)))

Answer (score -1):

Assuming DOB is a String you could write a UDF

```
def formatDate(s: String): String {
  // date formatting code
}

val formatDateUdf = udf(formatDate(_: String))

ds.select($"NAME", formatDateUdf($"DOB").as("DOB"))
```